# How to save object using its ID in Spring JPA?

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa

I'm using RabbitMQ to synchronise some tables in both their respective two databases, and I'd like them to have the same ID's.

When I receive one student from App A, I'd like App B to save the same student with its ID.

App B's Student table is currently empty. When App A sends a Student with ID=101, App B saves the same student using the save() function, but stores the record as ID=1. I know I can just get the same student object back from DB and update it, but is there a way to do this as I call the save function?

```
public class Student implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long student_id;
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;

    ...getters/setters

}
```

I'm using a MySQL database

Comment: Umm... don't use `@GeneratedValue` in App B? I don't quite follow what the problem is, is the `id` generated in App A not sent to App B?

Comment: I removed @GeneratedValue, but it didn't work. App A notifies App B to create a student with ID 200, but since the last student ID in App B's database is 10, it adds a row with ID 11.